# silex how to make route ending "/" optional

Tags: php, routes, silex

I am using Silex 1.1 and PHP 5.3, how do I make the ending "/" optional in a route?

Currently I have two routes doing the same thing

```
$app->get('/item/{id}/', function( $id ) use ($app) {
  /** Codes Here **/
});
$app->get('/item/{id}', function( $id ) use ($app) {
  /** Codes Here **/
});
```

Is it possible to specify the route only once where the ending "/" is optional? and how?

Thanks

Comment: If you define the route with a trailing slash, any request without trailing slash will return a 301 redirect to the correct one. So define `/item/{id}/` and any request to `/item/{id}` should return a 301 redirect to `/item/{id}/`.

Comment: Thanks! not sure if you want to post as answer so I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define the route with a trailing slash, any request without trailing slash will return a 301 redirect to the correct one. So define `/item/{id}/` and any request to `/item/{id}` should return a 301 redirect to `/item/{id}/`

Comment: but then ``/item/`` will not be reachable (no route found for '/item/')

Comment: @GDmac My solution has nothing to do with `/item/` which should be a different route. If you define it, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it replacing the `PATH_INFO` parameter in my own Request instance.

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', rtrim($request->server->get('REQUEST_URI'), "/"));

$app->run($request);
```